# Java jax - rs program to accept files from external systems

Tags: java, web-services, heroku, salesforce, jax-rs

I am trying to create a simple Java Jax-RS based webservice which accepts the file in a byte[] format or as a blob and pushes it to an FTP folder. This service is used by Salesforce to push files to directories via this Java API. For testing i have hosted this application in https://ftptransfer.herokuapp.com/myresource

I need to create a class which basically accepts files from external systems

```
package com.example;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataContentDisposition;
import org.glassfish.jersey.media.multipart.FormDataParam;


@Path("sendFiles")
public class FileTransfer {

    @POST
    @Consumes({MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA})
    public String uploadPdfFile(  ) 
    {        


        return "Uploaded successfully";

    }


}
```

Can some help with any good reference to achieve this, as i have tried many approaches from different blogs but none helped me much.

Answer (score 0):

I am able to achieve this in the following way

```
import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;

import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.ws.rs.POST;

@Path("sendFiles")
public class FileTransfer {

    @POST
    @Path("file")
    @Consumes("*/*")
    public String uploadPdfFile(InputStream fileInputStream) 
    {        
        FTPClient client = new FTPClient();
        boolean login;

        FileInputStream fis = null;
        int read = 0;
        byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
        OutputStream out;
        try {
            File file=new File("testhm001.txt"); 
            out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            while ((read = fileInputStream.read(bytes)) != -1)
            {
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);

            }
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder out1 = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out1.append(line);
            }

        return "done";
    }


}
```